# Pixel pattern overlay on website section - how is it done?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been trying to figure out how a pixel pattern overlay can be applied over a website section like in this site: http://www.tinkeringmonkey.com/ (over the background video image at top and image in bottom section)

I'm sure this is fairly straightforward, I just don't know what to google to try and find the css or whatever I need to implement it.

Thanks heaps for any replies!
David

Answer (score 0):

Here take a look [at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qgpvL1y/1/)

With pseudo element `:after`, you can add a repeated background and make its `position:absolute` with top-left-right-bottom to zero.

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
div:after {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/i/style/patterns/tileables/06/dot-grid-1.png) repeat;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the website using your browser's developer tools you will see that they have simply included an empty div, scaled it to 100% width and height of it's container, positioned it absolutely, given it a higher z-index than the video container and used a tile-able background image to produce the diagonal lines you see. In this instance the class applied to the div is called `mk-section-mask` and the css applied to that class is...

```
.mk-section-mask {
    background: url(../../images/video-mask.png) center center repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

where video-mask.png is a 4px square png with a diagonal line running through it... [See here](http://www.tinkeringmonkey.com/wp-content/themes/ken/images/video-mask.png)

Hope that helps

Dan

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want to know how a certain effect or layout is achieved, try the web inspecting tools in your browser. I use Google Chrome to develop sites, it comes with a [very complete tool set](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

As for your specific question, there's several ways to attain this. If you want to apply this overlay to a non-[void element](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/html5/void-elements-html5/), my approach would be using [HTML pseudo-elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp):

```
.overlay {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: url(path/to/your/transparent/overlay.png) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Apply the class `overlay` to whatever `<div>` and you're good to go. There's a catch, though: elements inside the `.overlay` won't respond to mouse/touch events, because the overlay on top will get them first.